# How can I delete a record when a user leaves the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a simple online shopping application where users can pick a product and add it to a cart. Carts are stored in the database, but when a user leaves the page those cart records are not deleted. How can I delete these records when a user leaves the page?

Answer (score 1):

This is what `session` is for. Store the `products_ids` in session.